# Show that $\Psi(S)$ is a Jordan null set

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open sets, $\Psi\colon U\to V$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and $S\subset\overline{S}\subset U$ a Jordan null set. Show that then $\Psi(S)$ is a Jordan null set, too.

Additionaly, I give you our definition of a Jordan null set:

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded subset. The outer Jordan volume of $M$ is defined by
$$
\text{vol}^*(M):=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{m}\text{vol}(Q_k) : Q_i\subset\mathbb{R}^n, i=1,...,m \text{ compact n-dim intervals with }M\subset\bigcup_{k=0}^{m}Q_k\right\}.
$$

In case of $\text{vol}^*(M)=0$ $M$ is called a Jordan null set.

---

So the task is to show that
$$
\text{vol}^*(\Psi(S))=0.
$$
Can you give me some help to show that? I have no idea at all...

**Update**

Found a proof, but do not understand it, nevertheless I cite it:

"Let $K\subset U$ be a compact upper set of the Jordan null set $S$ and set
$$
E:=\max_{x\in K}\lVert D\Psi(x)\rVert.
$$
By definition of the operatornorm $E$ is an upper bound for the expansion factor of the diffeomorphism $\Psi$ on the set $K$. Set
$$
r_K:=\max_{x\in K} d(x,J).
$$
Then it is
$$
\Psi(K)\subset\overline{B(J,E\cdot r_K)}."
$$

To be honest, I do not understand this proof at all. In case you do: Can you explain it to me, please?

With greetings

math12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited in response to comments)

Denote by $\Lambda_r$ the standard partition of ${\mathbb R}^n$ into cubes of side length $\rho:=2^{-r}$.

Concerning $S$ we have to assume that there is an $r\geq0$ and  set of $M$ cubes $B_k\in\Lambda_r$ such that $$S\subset B:=\bigcup_{k=1}^M B_k\subset U\ .\tag{1}$$
The building $B$ is compact; therefore there exists an $L>0$ with $\|d\Psi(x)\|\leq L$ for all $x\in B$. By the mean value theorem this implies that for any segment $[x,y]\subset B$ we have
$$|\Psi(y)-\Psi(x)|\leq L |y-x|\ .$$

Let an $\epsilon'>0$ be given. Then by assumption on $S$ we can find a set of $N$ boxes $Q_l$ of total volume $<\epsilon'/2$ such that
$$S\subset\bigcup_{l=1}^N Q_l\ .\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$$S\subset\bigcup_{l,\> k}Q_{lk}', \qquad Q_{lk}':=Q_l\cap B_k\ .$$
Choosing $r$ large enough we can ensure that each box $Q_{lk}'$ is contained in a union of $\Lambda_r$-cubes of total volume $<2{\rm vol}(Q_{lk}')$. This means that we may assume the $Q_l$ in $(2)$ to be $\Lambda_r$-cubes of total volume $<\epsilon'$.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. We have to construct a finite set of boxes $R_k\subset V$ of total volume $<\epsilon$ such that $$\Psi(S)\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^N R_k\ .$$
To this end we choose a covering $(1)$ of $S$ whose total volume is $<\epsilon'$, where $\epsilon'$ will be determined at the end of the proof, by reverse engineering.

Consider a fixed $Q_l$ and  two points $x$, $y\in Q_l$. About the $i$th coordinate of the image points $\Psi(x)$, $\Psi(y)$ we can say the following:
$$|\Psi_i(y)-\Psi_i(x)|\leq |\Psi(y)-\Psi(x)|\leq L|y-x|\leq L\sqrt{n}\>\rho\ .$$
It follows that $\Psi(Q_l)$ is contained in a cube $R_l$ of side length $L\sqrt{n}\>\rho$, so that
$${\rm vol}(R_l)=L^n\>n^{n/2}\rho^n=L^n n^{n/2}\>{\rm vol}(Q_l)\ .$$
This shows that we should take $$\epsilon':={\epsilon\over L^n n^{n/2}}\ .$$
It then follows that
$$\Psi(S)\subset\bigcup_{l=1}^N\Psi(Q_l)\subset\bigcup_{l=1}^N R_l$$
with
$$\sum_{l=1}^N{\rm vol}(R_l)= L^n n^{n/2}\sum_{l=1}^N{\rm vol}(Q_l)< L^n n^{n/2}\>\epsilon'=\epsilon\ .$$

Comment: Why do we know $$|\Psi_i(x)-\Psi_i(y)|\leq |\Psi(x)-\Psi(y)|\leq L|x-y|\leq L\sqrt{n}\>\rho_k\ .$$? Do you mean $\text{vol}^*$ in the end?

Comment: I thank you very much for that beautiful proof. Besides that: Can you explain that proof to me that I cited in my post? I do not understand this proof, maybe you do.

Comment: $K$ and $E$ correspond to my $B$ and $L$. It is not explained what $J$ is, let alone $\overline{B(\ldots)}$.

Comment: I do not know what $J$ is. I think $\overline{B(...)}$ is the closed ball..

Comment: Is it possible that $J$ stands for Jordan measurable sets?

Comment: Its not totally clear to me why we can assume that the $Q_k$ are cubes... and why there is $\leqslant$ in your last inequality and not $=$.

Comment: And do you use the mean value theorem for each coordinate and because it is right for each coordinate it is right?